# functional calculus

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Suppose $A$ is a non-unital $C^*$ algebra, $B$ is another $C^*$ algebra. Suppose $\phi: A \to B$ is a non-zero $*$-homomorphism and $x_0$ is a normal elememt in $A$, by the continuous functional calculus, we have  $\phi(f(x_0))=f(\phi(x_0))$ for any $f\in C_0（\sigma_{A}(x_0))$. 
My question is: can we choose a function $f\in C_0（\sigma_{A}(x_0))$ such that $|\phi(f(x_0))\|>1$?

Comment: If you can find a function $f$ such that $\phi(f)\neq0$, can you see why this is true?

Comment: If $\phi(x_0)\neq0$,you mean that $f(z)=z,z\in C_0（\sigma_{A}(x_0))$ is suitable?But how to ensure that $|\phi(f(x_0))\|\geq1$?

Answer (score 0):

By Urysohn's lemma, we can always choose a continuous function that vanishes at infinity with $f(z)=10000$ at a fixed point $z$. So, $\|\phi(f(x_0))\|=\|f(\phi(x_0))\|=\|f\|>9999$.

Comment: Probably, the OP wants that $f(\phi(x_0)) \in B$ and so one should also require that $f(0) = 0$. This however is no problem, since the spectrum of $\phi(x_0)$  contains points other than zero. E.g. $f(z) =  \lambda z$ for some large $\lambda > 0$.